# Position fixed child on top of next element with z-index relative

Tags: html, css

I need to make child below parent to bo on top of relative element, is it possible to do it ?

```
<div class="parent fixed">
  <div class="child absolute">
</div>
<div class="next-element relative">
```

Now css:

```
.parent {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.child {
    position: absolute;
}
.next-element {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: Is the z-index for the next-element mandatory? What does it mean if so?

Comment: if i remove that z-index from next-element i still can't make child be on top of it, its because of position: relative; at next-element

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure I understand the problem, but if the z-index of parent (and hence its child) is greater than the z-index of the next item then the child will be 'on top of' next element.

Here's a simple snippet with the elements given dimensions so they can be seen and next element given z-index -1 just to make it less than the first element (where z-index defaults to 0).

```css
.parent {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: lime;
}

.next-element {
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent fixed">
  <div class="child absolute">
  </div>
  <div class="next-element relative">
```

Comment: I explained it wrong, what i want achive is:

 "parent" is an fixed header on left side
"child" is submenu inside parent that need to show on next-element on hover
"next-element" is the content of website

Comment: So, is there any problem with having parent at a higher z-index than the rest of the stuff? In my snippet just put the parent z-index to 1 and take out the next element's z-index.

Comment: I post example on top what i wanna make.

Comment: So, why not try it with the z-indexes as I have suggested rather than leave the z-index of content (the next element in your question) as 1? Also, please put the code in your question as it isn't an answer.

Comment: If you make header with higher z-index then content it will be on top of content i dont wanna this.